# Using score as value

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I use player score as normal integer value? My goal is to do something like: `/setblock <value of score of @e[name=x0, type=armor_stand] in args objective> ...`

EDIT:

I know I can simulate that using some other commands, but is there any way to do this directly, as I can do in programming languages?

Comment: As I said, Minecraft isn't a programming language and you're going to miss a lot more if you see it that way. This was one of the things I meant.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do it like you imagine. The best you can do is to teleport an armor stand as many times as the number in the scoreboard is, like this:

```
/summon armor_stand 0 ~ ~ {NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"scoreToCoordinate"}
```

Loop:

```
/execute @p[score_coordinate_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=scoreToCoordinate] ~1 ~ ~
/scoreboard players remove @p[score_coordinate_min=1] coordinate 1
```

Currently this would go to -infinity for the score and there are a lot more optimisations that can be done (for example something like a binary search) and it relies on the chunk with the armor stand in it to be loaded, etc., but that's the main idea.

If you really need this, you should probably do a binary search through the world and teleport the player to make sure that the chunks are loaded. It's not nice, but it works if you absolutely need it.